# Update sql row without deleting data

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to do such thing?

```
UPDATE news SET article_title="["+id+"]" + article_title;
```

Is it possible to process this query for every row in the news table?
I want to add the id of the article to the article title like this:
[1000] StackOverFlow

Kind regards!

Comment: Yes you *can* do this, but why *would* you? You have all data needed, neatly separated as it should be and you can always get the concatenation of id and title on-the-fly. (And if you want to save yourself from having to type the concatenation everytime, create a view.)

Comment: Please learn basic MySQL syntax. `+` is for adding numbers, not concatenating strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is:

```
UPDATE news SET article_title=CONCAT('[',id,'] ',article_title);
```

You could also add a trigger on your table `news` to it do this update automatically. It would be something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_news 
   BEFORE INSERT ON news
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       NEW.article_title = CONCAT('[',id,'] ', NEW.article_title);
   END;
```

Note that this trigger would work only on an `INSERT` command. That is because for an `update` you would have to parse the `article_title` so you don't end up with something like: `[1] someName[1] someName`